# Merge elements in array using dataweave

Tags: dataweave

Input:

```
{
  "letterCountArray": [
    {
      "letter": "A",
      "count": 5
    },
    {
      "letter": "B",
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "letter": "C",
      "count": 6
    },
    {
      "letter": "D",
      "count": 5
    },
    {
      "letter": "E",
      "count": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
  {
    "count D+E": 11
  }
```

I've tried the following dataweave without success:

```
%dw 1.0 
%input payload application/json
%output application/json
---
payload.letterCountArray filter ($.letter == "D" or $.letter == "E") map { "countD+E": $ reduce ($ + $) }
```

Comment: Input Json
+++++++
{"letterCountArray": [
{"letter": "A","count": 5},
{"letter": "B","count": 3},
{"letter": "C","count": 6},
{"letter": "D","count": 5},
{"letter": "E","count": 6}]}

Expected Output
++++
 [
          {
            "count D+E": 11
          }
        ]
        

I have tried as below
+++
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/json
---
payload.letterCountArray filter ($.letter == "D" or $.letter == "E") 
map {
 "countD+E": $ reduce ($ + $)
 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will sum the elements:

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/json
---
"count D+E": sum (payload.letterCountArray filter ($.letter == "D" or $.letter == "E") map (
    $.count
))
```